# How to create duplicate rows using Pivot Table Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, pivot-table

I want to create duplicate rows for a dataframe in python. The dataframe looks like this

```
SKU Ids wk_1 wk_2 wk_3 wk_4 wk_5 wk_6    

 10 20  1    2    3     4    5    6
 30 40  6    5    4     3    2    1
```

I want the output as

```
SKU Ids wk   value
 10 20 wk_1   1
 10 20 wk_2   2
 10 20 wk_3   3
 10 20 wk_4   4
 10 20 wk_5   5
 10 20 wk_6   6
 30 40 wk_1   6
 30 40 wk_2   5
 30 40 wk_3   4
 30 40 wk_4   3
 30 40 wk_5   2
 30 40 wk_6   1
```

I am trying to use pivot_table, but it is showing me error

```
hqp = hq.pivot_table(columns=['sku', 'ids','value'], 
index= ['sku', 'ids'], 
values = ['wk_1', 'wk_2', 'wk_3', 'wk_4','wk_5', 'wk_6'])
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how `wide_to_long` build for

```
pd.wide_to_long(df,['wk'],i=['SKU','Ids'],j='value',sep='_').reset_index()
Out[28]: 
    SKU  Ids  value  wk
0    10   20      1   1
1    10   20      2   2
2    10   20      3   3
3    10   20      4   4
4    10   20      5   5
5    10   20      6   6
6    30   40      1   6
7    30   40      2   5
8    30   40      3   4
9    30   40      4   3
10   30   40      5   2
11   30   40      6   1
```

Comment: Learnt new function :-).

Answer (score 3):

Set `SKU` and `Ids` as index and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['SKU','Ids'])\
       .stack().reset_index()\
       .rename(columns={'level_2':'wk',0:'value'})
```

Or:

```
df = df.set_index(['SKU','Ids'])\
       .stack().reset_index(name='value')\
       .rename(columns={'level_2':'wk'})
```

Or as per [`W-B`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53340984/8320861) suggestion in comments one more method using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['SKU','Ids'])\
       .rename(columns={'variable':'wk'})\
       .sort_values(['SKU','Ids'])
```

---

```
print(df)
    SKU  Ids    wk  value
0    10   20  wk_1      1
1    10   20  wk_2      2
2    10   20  wk_3      3
3    10   20  wk_4      4
4    10   20  wk_5      5
5    10   20  wk_6      6
6    30   40  wk_1      6
7    30   40  wk_2      5
8    30   40  wk_3      4
9    30   40  wk_4      3
10   30   40  wk_5      2
11   30   40  wk_6      1
```

Comment: If you can just using `melt` instead of `stack `for the performance

Comment: @W-B I checked first `melt` but it not preserving the order. But a good option too. You can include it in answer or I will for reference.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa chain with sort_value